# Chain functions with callbacks TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

After reading an article about [Handling Failure](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/posts/functional-c-handling-failures-input-errors/) by Vladimir Khorikov, I try to implement it using TypeScript.

The [example code](https://gist.github.com/vkhorikov/7852c7606f27c52bc288) was written in C#, which I can understand only the idea, not the code.

Here is my implementation so far.

```
export class Result<T> {
  success: boolean;
  private error: string | null;
  private _value: T;

  get value(): T {
    if (!this.success) {
      throw new Error('Cannot get value of an error result.');
    }

    return this._value;
  }

  get errorMessage(): string {
    if (this.success || this.error === null) {
      throw new Error('Cannot get error message of a success result.');
    }

    return this.error;
  }

  get failure(): boolean {
    return !this.success;
  }

  private constructor(success: boolean, error: string | null, value?: T) {
    if (success && error != null) {
      throw new Error('Success result cannot have error message');
    }

    if (!success && (error === null || error.length === 0)) {
      throw new Error('Failed result must have error message');
    }

    this.success = success;
    this.error = error;
    this._value = value as T;
  }

  /**
   * Create failure result
   * @param errorMessage error message
   * @returns failureResult
   */
  static fail<T>(errorMessage: string): Result<T> {
    return new Result(false, errorMessage);
  }

  /**
   * Create success result
   * @param value
   * @returns successResult
   */
  static ok<T>(value?: T): Result<T> {
    return new Result(true, null, value);
  }

  /**
   * Combine multiple results into one result
   * @param results
   * @returns result
   */
  static combine(...results: Result<any>[]): Result<any> {
    for (let result of results) {
      if (result.failure) {
        return result;
      }
    }

    return Result.ok();
  }

  /**
   * Do things on success result
   * @param func
   * @returns result
   */
  onSuccess(func: Function): Result<T> {
    if (this.success) {
      func();
    }

    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Do things on failure result
   * @param func
   * @returns result
   */
  onFailure(func: Function): Result<T> {
    if (this.failure) {
      func();
    }

    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Do things on both success and failure result
   * @param func
   * @returns result
   */
  onBoth(func: Function): Result<T> {
    func();

    return this;
  }
}
```

I am struggling to implement the chain functions.

In the example code, the `onSuccess`, `onFailure`, and `onBoth` functions are chained beautifully.

```
return Result.Combine(billingInfoResult, customerNameResult)
        .OnSuccess(() => _paymentGateway.ChargeCommission(billingInfoResult.Value))
        .OnSuccess(() => new Customer(customerNameResult.Value))
        .OnSuccess(
            customer => _repository.Save(customer)
                .OnFailure(() => _paymentGateway.RollbackLastTransaction())
        )
        .OnSuccess(() => _emailSender.SendGreetings(customerNameResult.Value))
        .OnBoth(result => Log(result))
        .OnBoth(result => CreateResponseMessage(result));
```

But in my code, it can only trigger void function. The function can't pass its result to the next function.

Could you show me how to implement this? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: JavaScript has `.next()` for promises. Are you sure you need the Result object to do the same thing?

Comment: The functions must return an instance of `Result<T>` in his example, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Maybe look at [Expressive error handling in TypeScript...](https://medium.com/inato/expressive-error-handling-in-typescript-and-benefits-for-domain-driven-design-70726e061c86).

Comment: @Invizi Where is `next()` defined on a Promise? I've seen it on iterators, but Promises have `then()`, `catch()`, `finally()` on instances...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I meant then, been using another language where it's next instead.

Comment: @Invizi I have first used `Either` before switching to `Result` type. `Result` type is more meaningful in my opinion. I will try to get some idea in the article to implement to the `Result` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the idea of the [article](https://medium.com/inato/expressive-error-handling-in-typescript-and-benefits-for-domain-driven-design-70726e061c86) that was suggested by Invizi, I have come up with this solution.

```
 onSuccess<U>(fn: (value: T) => U): Result<U> {
    if (this.success) {
      return Result.ok(fn(this._value))
    }

    return Result.fail(this.errorMessage)
  }
```

This makes the chain flexible with type just like the example code.

```
Result.combine(Rectangle.from(5, 5), Rectangle.from(1, 1))
  .onSuccess(() => {return new User('user')}) // Create new user
  .onSuccess(user => console.log(user.name)) // Print user name
```

Comment: This is not an `onSuccess` function, this is known as `fmap` (or just `map`).

Comment: @Bergi It basically changes from one type to another type, so it may look like `map`. `map` is used in array, but this is used in object. I get this idea from the article I have mentioned above, so I don't know if he got this idea from `map` or not :)

Comment: It does look like `map` because that is the method that all [functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor_(functional_programming)) share. Yes, array is also a functor, just like `Result` or the equivalent `Either` type from the other article (the latter term is more common in functional programming).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be implementing it differently?

Original Code shows:

```cs
public static Result OnSuccess(this Result result, Func<Result> func)
{
    if (result.Failure)
        return result;

    return func();
}
```

which would translate to:

```
onSuccess(fn: () => Result): Result {
    if (this.failure)
        return this;

    return fn();
}
```

but you have

```
onSuccess(func: Function): Result<T> {
    if (this.success) {
      func();
    }

    return this;
}
```

Comment: So, the OP is missing the `return` before `func();`? That's really the only difference I see, besides a more specific typing of the function.

Comment: Also the `failure` check instead of `success`. Thought it might be helpful to point out in case it was done by mistake.

Comment: This only return `Result` type, but in the example code, the `OnSuccess` could return `Customer` type, which is not `Result` type at all. If we let the function return `any`, then we could not chain the functions anymore.