# TypeScript - Return function value from the callback function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using the Error Handling method using the `Result` type, which I have posted [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70119294/12765965).

Using the `Result` type, I could easily build a chain of functions like this

```
Result.combine(result1, result2)
.onFailure(err => doSomethingOnFailure())
.onSuccess(val => doSomethingOnSuccess())
```

This flow looks good for me, but I have a problem.

```
function func(a, b) {
// Some code above
const result = Result.comine(aResult, bResult).onFailure(err => {
// I want to return fail result to the func here but do not know how
}).onSuccess(() => {
// Do something on success
})

// So I have to do a simple if check
if (result.failure) {
// Return fail result here
}
// Then do something on success here
}
```

I want to return the fail result to the parent function inside the `onFailure` function.

Could I somehow achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean to write `Result.combine` instead of `comine` ? Also - what is the problem you are seeing ?

Comment: @Pogrindis In the `Result` type, which is in the linked question above, I have a static method `combine` to get the failure result in a `Result` array if one of them failed. The problem I am seeing is also mentioned in the code above. I want to return the value from the `onFailure` callback to the wrapper function named `func` without using an `if` statement to check.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing two separate `onFailure` and `onSuccess` methods that just execute a side effect and return the `Result` instance itself, use a single method for both handlers that returns the result of the respective call:

```
handle<U>(onSuccess: (value: T) => U, onFailure: (error: string) => U): U {
  if (this.success) {
    return onSuccess(this._value);
  } else {
    return onFailure(this.error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Writing two separate `onFailure` and `onSuccess` enhances the readability

Comment: …but doesn't work when you want to get an arbitrary value back instead of another `Result`

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear what I want to describe. If I use `handle` method like you, I have to return it, but I also want to do something after that. All I want is to somehow break out of the function and return the value from `onFailure`. If the `Result` is success, then the code will execute after the `Result`. You can think of it being used in the validation process.

Comment: @NgọcNguyễn What is the `func` expected to return? A `Result` object? Something else? Nothing?

Comment: I want to return a `Result` object to the `func`.

Comment: Is it possible to return a value from a callback function to the wrapper function?

Comment: I don't quite understand. What does the callback function return that you want to forward  to the outer function?

Comment: You might want to use an existing library that provides `Result`/`Either`, and get familiar with all the methods it provides (`map`, `fold`, `chain`/`flatMap`), before writing your own.

Comment: Maybe I should try to use existing library first like you said :)